# Javascript: eliminar comillas arreglo

Tags: javascript, array

tengo el siguiente caso :

Tengo este arreglo que tiene n elementos y cada objeto llega en parejas separados por coma:

```
let arr = ["1.1,0.1", "13.5,5.4", "5.0,1.0"]
```

debo convertirlo de la siguiente manera :

```
let arr = [1.1,0.1,13.5,5.4,5.0,1.0]
```

Quitando las comillas y que los números queden parseados.

Estoy intentando lo siguiente :

```
let jh = ''
let al = []
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
 jh += arr[i].replace(/"/g, "");
}
al.push(jh)
console.log(al)
```

Con una salida como esta, pero los números se juntan:

```
[ '1.1,0.113.5,5.45.0,1.0' ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

¿Qué tal con algo así?

```js
let fin = [];
let arr = ["1.1,0.1", "13.5,5.4", "5.0,1.0"];
arr.forEach(element => {//Para cada valor del array
    element.split(",").forEach(elm => {//Lo divido en 2 por la coma y para cada uno de los resultados
        fin.push(parseFloat(elm));//LO meto en el array fin haciéndole un parse a float para evitar comillas
    });
});
console.log(fin);
```

Si no entiendes algo pregunta, he puesto explicaciones en el código por si acaso.

Comment: Gracias benito , muy óptima su solución.

Answer (score 3):

Primero tendrás que recorrer el arrar, luego, a cada elemento le aplicaremos el método `split`, pasándole como parámetro el separador para convertirlo a `array`, en este caso el separador seria la **coma**.

```js
const lastArr = ["1.1,0.1", "13.5,5.4", "5.0,1.0"]
const newArr = []

for (let i = 0; i < lastArr.length; i++) {
  const str = lastArr[i]
  
  const otherArr = lastArr[i].split(",")
  
  for (let e = 0; e < otherArr.length; e++) {
    newArr.push(parseFloat(otherArr[e]))
  }
}

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: Ya esta esta editado :D

Comment: Muchas gracias Samuel

Answer (score 1):

aquí te dejo una solución usando built-in functions de javascript. De esta manera dejas tu código cortito y bonito.

[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

[flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

[parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

---

Aqui esta el código con comentarios.

```
let array = ["1.1,0.1", "13.5,5.4", "5.0,1.0"]
// Resultado deseado = [1.1,0.1,13.5,5.4,5.0,1.0]

function quitarComillas(array) {
  // Usamos .map para mutar e iterar sobre el array.
  // Usando .split separamos cada elemento por el caracter que definimos en este caso la ','
  // ahora esto lo convirtio a un array de arrays
  // [ [ '1.1', '0.1' ], [ '13.5', '5.4' ], [ '5.0', '1.0' ] ]
  // gracias al bendito .flat() esto lo que haria es convertir de nuestro nuestro arrays de arrays
  // a un array de 5 elementos
  // [ '1.1', '0.1', '13.5', '5.4', '5.0', '1.0' ]
  // y esto que asignado a la variable arraySinComas
  let arraySinComas = array.map( elemento => elemento.split(',')).flat()
  // Ahora con el .map volvemos a iterar por el arraySinComas y parseamos cada elemento
  // y esto lo asginamos a una nueva variable
  let arraySinComillas = arraySinComas.map( elemento => parseFloat(elemento))
  // Y aca podes imprimir o hacer un return si necesitas.
  console.log(arraySinComillas)
}

quitarComillas(array)
```

```js
let array = ["1.1,0.1", "13.5,5.4", "5.0,1.0"]
function quitarComillas(array) {
  let arraySinComas = array.map( elemento => elemento.split(',')).flat()
  let arraySinComillas = arraySinComas.map( elemento => parseFloat(elemento))
  console.log(arraySinComillas)
}

quitarComillas(array)
```